# How to specify core instance node when submitting Spark step to AWS EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running multiple instances for my EMR cluster on AWS.
I have 2 instances of CORE nodes and 1 MASTER node

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.add_job_flow_steps

I'm using PySpark to submit the job but don't see anything on specifying the CORE node to run this on.
I thought this is done automatically (like round-robin style?)

Is there way to acheive this?

Comment: what do you mean by CORE nodes, do you mean executors?

Comment: "Core Nodes" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html .  "there can be multiple core nodes—and therefore multiple EC2 instances—in the instance group or instance fleet. There is only one core instance group or instance fleet. With instance groups, you can add and remove EC2 instances while the cluster is running or set up automatic scaling."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always submit your step to the master not the core nodes. The master will then distribute the task to the cluster's workers (Spark executors in the core or task nodes).